# "This class is not key value > coding-compliant for the key previewB" but I've deleted previewB

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've deleted a button from a nib file.
I've also deleted the outlet and IBAction associated with that button.
I've cleaned my project and uninstalled the app.

However I still get the following error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key previewB.'

But if I search for previewB in my workspace I can't find anything. I've deleted it from ComposerViewController.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that you don't still have a connection somewhere in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2):

If you're certain you've removed all references from the XIB, try deleting the file (delete reference only), cleaning, and then re-adding the file.

Comment: Well, actually previewB is still in the source of the xib file, but is editing the source the only way to get rid of it ?

Comment: Then as Simon said, you still have a reference to it in the XIB. I was merely thinking that IB, especially integrated in Xcode 4, sometimes does some unwanted caching.